# How to connect MongoDB and MySQL in same project(app) in Yii/Yii2?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, yii, yii2

I have a requirement to use two types of databases in single project/app. Now I am confused how to do that. I tried individual and they worked but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: The question/issue is not clear. Please add some working code for those cases when single DB works, how you try to combine them and describe what you expect and what actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Yii 2 you can set two db components in configuration like:

```
'components' => [
    'dbMySQL' => [
        'class' => '\yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:...',
        'username' => '...',
        'password' => '...',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
    'dbMongo' => [
        'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mongodb://...',
    ],
],
```

and then use it where you want

```
Yii::$app->dbMySQL->...
Yii::$app->dbMongo->...
```

Remember to override `getDb()` method in `\yii\db\ActiveRecord` and `\yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord` classes to point to these components if you use ActiveRecords.